# How can I use for loop to extract a specific length of string before and after my pattern

Tags: python

I have a `string='acbgfhtyesdktAAAAkghtruejdsdyhuiAAAAncgdsdgtef'`.

I want to use for loop to extract string with a specific length before and after 'AAAA'.

For example I want my output to be `['dkt', 'kgh', 'hui', 'ncg']`

> string.split('AAAA')

can give me what I want but it does not give me strings with length of 3 character.

I need to use for loop to generalize it.

Comment: Do you *need* to use a loop, or can you use regex? `re.findall(r'(...)AAAA(...)', your_string)` returns `[('dkt', 'kgh'), ('hui', 'ncg')]` (use the regex exactly as written, the "..." is intentional)

Comment: @Green you'll need to flatten the result but that's what I was thinking... It does strike me as an exercise though, so not sure regex would be an acceptable answer...

Comment: Why not just do string split and then pick the sub string via index? (for after it is obvious but for before you can use a negative index.)

Answer (score 2):

If you *must* use a `for` loop, then you could maybe do something like this:

```
def my_method(my_str):
    # split the string as desired
    segments = my_str.split('AAAA')
    # make an empty output list to add things to
    output = []
    # iterate through all segments except the last
    for idx in range(len(segments) - 1):
        # take the last three characters of each segment, 
        # and the first three characters of the next segment, 
        # and add them to output
        output = output + [segments[idx][-3:], segments[idx + 1][:3]]
    return output

print(my_method('acbgfhtyesdktAAAAkghtruejdsdyhuiAAAAncgdsdgtef'))
# ['dkt', 'kgh', 'hui', 'ncg']
```

A solution I would prefer would be to use regex and then flatten it:

```
import re

def my_method2(my_str):
    return [e for s in re.findall(r'(...)AAAA(...)', my_str) for e in s]

print(my_method2('acbgfhtyesdktAAAAkghtruejdsdyhuiAAAAncgdsdgtef'))
# ['dkt', 'kgh', 'hui', 'ncg']
```